# More idiomatic way of reading JSON file and creating a map from it in Scala

Tags: json, scala

In the code snippet below I am reading a JSON file with a structure similar to this one:

```
{ "c7254865-87b5-4d34-a7bd-6ba6c9dbab14": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
{ "36c18403-1707-48c4-8f19-3b2e705007d4": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
{ "34a71a88-ae2d-4304-a1db-01c54fc6e4d8": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
```

Each line contains a key value pair which should be then added to a map in Scala. This is the Scala code which I used for this purpose:

```
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new Configuration())

def readFile(location: String): mutable.HashMap[String, String] = {
  val path: Path = new Path(location)
  val dataInputStream: FSDataInputStream = fs.open(path)
  val m = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
  for (line <- Source.fromInputStream(dataInputStream).getLines) {
    val parsed: Option[Any] = JSON.parseFull(line)
    m ++= parsed.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
  }
  m
}
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this in Scala for sure. Especially you should be able to get rid of the mutable map and ingest the lines directly via a stream into a map. How can you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val r: Map[String, String] = Source.fromInputStream(dataInputStream).getLines
    .map(line => JSON.parseFull(line).get)
    .flatMap { case m: Map[String, String] => m.map { case (k, v) => k -> v } }
    .toMap
```

Keep in mind that `JSON` (you mean `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON`, right?) is itself marked `@deprecated` in Scala 2.11

EDIT: as per suggestions of @SergGr and @Dima, this can be further simplified as

```
val r: Map[String, String] = Source.fromInputStream(dataInputStream).getLines
    .flatMap(line => JSON.parseFull(line))
    .collect { case m: Map[String, String] => m }
    .flatten.toMap
```

The last correction also has better handling of unexpected JSON (e.g, if an array is passed in)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the deprecation in Scala 2.11. Which  would be the alternative?

Comment: Why do you need such a complicated `flatMap` with inner `map`? `Map` is already `Iterable` so `json.getLines
.flatMap(line => JSON.parseFull(line).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])
        .toMap` should be enough

Comment: @gil.fernandes Usually they list the alternative with the deprecation marker, but no alternative was listed in this case. My guess is that they didn't want to promote any specific JSON library, as there are several out there. I've been using Jackson all along, but SO discourages opinion-based recommendations

Comment: @gil.fernandes, I believe that the most popular choices (in no particular order) are [json4s](https://json4s.org), [Play Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) and [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/). Take a look and choose whatever you like.

Comment: @SergGr The main difference between case match and using `asInstanceOf` is that the former wouldn't fail if you suddenly get an unexpected type. `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON` can return either a `Map[String, Any]`, or `List[Any]`, thus the need for a case match. If switching to another library that has more controlled JSON parsing, then we can get by without the case match. I'll upvote, as this is a valid point in some cases

Comment: By the way: I like your answer, so +1.

Comment: @AlexSavitsky, although I don't quite agree I can see your point for the outer pattern match, but what is the reason for the inner `map`/pattern match? AFAIU `m.map { case (k, v) => k -> v }` does exactly nothing useful if `m` is known to be a `Map`.

Comment: @AlexSavitsky, Sorry for being a nitpicker, but how is the pattern match that matches only `Map[String, Any]` is better than `asInstanceOfMap[String, Any]`? If the `JSON.parseFull` call actually returned `List[Any]`, your pattern match will fail as well with `scala.MatchError`. How is this better? IMHO pattern match is better only if you are a bit paranoid and cover there all the cases.

Comment: You don't need `.get` (it's kinda code smell) ... just replace the first `.map` with `.flatMap`

Comment: You can also replace second `.flatMap` with `.collect` and .`.flatten` to address @SergGr's  concern about result having a wrong type

Answer (score 0):

```
val json =scala.io.Source.fromString("""
 { "c7254865-87b5-4d34-a7bd-6ba6c9dbab14": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
 { "36c18403-1707-48c4-8f19-3b2e705007d4": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
 { "34a71a88-ae2d-4304-a1db-01c54fc6e4d8": "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}
 """)
```

Split the string, then map each entry in the `Array` to a key and value, and then convert to a `Map`. This returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]`

```
scala> json.map(x => x.split(":")).map(x => x(0) -> x(1)).toMap

res35: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(
 { "c7254865-87b5-4d34-a7bd-6ba6c9dbab14" -> " "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}",
 { "36c18403-1707-48c4-8f19-3b2e705007d4" -> " "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}",
 { "34a71a88-ae2d-4304-a1db-01c54fc6e4d8" -> " "72119c87-7fce-4e17-9770-fcfab04328f5"}")
```

Comment: I cannot read the JSON from a string. I need to read it from a file. And the file will be around 100KB or more.

Comment: @gil.fernandes, although I prefer Alex's answer to be fair  `json` is just a `Source` and it doesn't matter whether it came from file or from a string just for test.

Comment: I understand that. `getLines` from a `DataInputStream` and from a `String` return the same thing. It's easier to work with your example from a `String`. The `for` statement and return value `m` can be replaced with the line I have above.